# Change an li class name in a wordpress custom menu walker

Tags: menus, navigation, walker, list

I'm building a nav that has a class applied to the main LI's and the nested LI's.  Example:

```
<ul>
<li class="className">Test</li>
<li class="className">Test
    <ul>
        <li class="ADifferentclassName">test</li>
        <li class="ADifferentclassName">test</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I've figured out how to get classes on the UL's and all the LI's, but I can figure out how to get a different class on the nested LI's.

Here is my custom walker:

This changes the nest UL class

```
 class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-main-sub-list\">\n";
  }
```

This strips out all the extraneous wordpress classes and adds the class nav-main-item to all the li's

```
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args )
    {

        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty ( $item->attr_title )
            // Avoid redundant titles
            and $item->attr_title !== $item->title
            and $attributes .= ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';

        ! empty ( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"';

        $attributes  = trim( $attributes );
        $title       = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output = "$args->before<a $attributes>$args->link_before$title</a>"
                        . "$args->link_after$args->after";

        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.


        $output .= $indent . '<li class="nav-main-item">';

        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
            ,   $item_output
            ,   $item
            ,   $depth
            ,   $args
        );
    }   

}
```

I just can't figure out how to change the class on the nested LI's.  Nothing I've done has worked.  Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Troubleshooting

Enabling the `WP_DEBUG` constant in `wp-config.php` exposed the following errors:

#### - Function Signatures

If Strict Standards is enabled, you'll see an error detailing incompatible method signatures. Though not absolutely necessary, I like to eliminate as many errors as possible. To correct this, the new `Walker_Nav_Menu` class's `start_el()` and `start_lvl()` methods' declarations need to match [those of `Walker_Nav_Menu` class itself](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L47) such that the new class can function as a drop-in replacement for the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class without throwing all sorts of parameter/argument related errors.

This:

```
class Wpse_145991_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
        //...
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

should become this:

```
class Wpse_145991_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        //...
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

#### - `Notice: Undefined variable: indent`

Near the bottom of the new class's `start_el()` method you'll see the line

```
$output .= $indent . '<li class="nav-main-item">';
```

But `$indent` is never defined within method. `Walker` classes tend to set an `$indent` variable for formatting HTML white-space to a count of `$depth` tab-characters. It's not functionally relevant, but this can be corrected by defining `$indent` somewhere before the aforementioned line:

```
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
```

At this point, the implementation posted in the question should be producing a menu without throwing any errors or warnings.

---

### Specifying Different Classes for Different Depths

#### Theory

When a `Walker_Nav_Menu` is `walk()`ing, both the `start_el()` and `start_lvl()` methods are passed a `$depth` argument that can be thought of as representative of the number of "levels," "submenus," or `<ul>` elements between the current item and the data root (i.e. the top-level `<ul>` element.

[image: Walker_Nav_Menu $depth Parameter]

#### Implementation

By conditionally branching based on this `$depth`, you can assign different classes for different elements & levels. For instance, using a `switch` would allow you to fine-tune classes for each item and level:

```
class Wpse_145991_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );

        // Select a CSS class for this `<ul>` based on $depth
        switch( $depth ) {
            case 0:
                // Top-level submenus get the 'nav-main-sub-list' class
                $class = 'nav-main-sub-list';
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                // Submenus nested 1-3 levels deep get the 'nav-other-sub-list' class
                $class = 'nav-other-sub-list';
                break;
            default:
                // All other submenu `<ul>`s receive no class
                break;
        }

        // Only print out the 'class' attribute if a class has been assigned
        if( isset( $class ) )
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"$class\">\n";
        else
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty ( $item->attr_title )
        // Avoid redundant titles
        and $item->attr_title !== $item->title
        and $attributes .= ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';

        ! empty ( $item->url )
        and $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"';

        $attributes  = trim( $attributes );
        $title       = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output = "$args->before<a $attributes>$args->link_before$title</a>"
                       . "$args->link_after$args->after";

        // Select a CSS class for this `<li>` based on $depth
        switch( $depth ) {
            case 0:
                // Top-level `<li>`s get the 'nav-main-item' class
                $class = 'nav-main-item';
                break;
            default:
                // All other `<li>`s receive no class
                break;
        }

        // Only print out the 'class' attribute if a class has been assigned
        if( isset( $class ) )
            $output .= $indent . '<li class="'. $class . '">';
        else
            $output .= $indent '<li>';

        $output .= apply_filters(
                'walker_nav_menu_start_el',
                $item_output,
                $item,
                $depth,
                $args
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response!  I follow some of what you've done here - but I am having a hard time implementing changes successfully.  For instance, the line  if( $depth > 0 ) {
        $class = 'menu-item-first-level';
    else
        $class = 'menu-item-other-level';

Comment: else
        $class = 'menu-item-other-level';
is giving me an error.  I'm trying to apply the class nav-main-item to top level LI's and the class nav-main-sub-item to second level li's and nav-main-sub-list to second level UL's.  It seems like $depth > 0 will apply the .nav-main-item  class to all levels?

I suppose i could handle this with css - but I'd like to try and figure this out.

Comment: Hey sorry about that - I definitely had a mismatched bracket, there. You were right about `$depth > 0` applying to the wrong items - I got my conditions backwards, sorry about that! I may have spoken too soon - I need to play with this, for a moment, and then I'll get back to you.

Comment: No problem - I appreciate your help immensely.  I've been working on this for too long and not having much luck finding answers.  Something about the wordpress codex is very confusing to me.

Comment: The updates worked and your explanation was superb!

Comment: Hey awesome - I'm glad you got it working! I've re-written my answer to address the issues brought up in these comments and to improve readability/conciseness. Cheers, Steph :)